# Сравнить список установленных пакетов dpkg

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите написать функцию на Python для автоматизации установки, которая будет проверять установлены ли пакеты Debian, с заданным списком. Если в полученном списке не хватает каких-то пакетов, то доустанавливает его, а если какие-то пакеты лишние, то удаляет их.

*Python ограничен только стандартными модулями, в уже настроенных функциях используются модули os и subprocess.*

Comment: А что за "лишние" пакеты? Т.е. на вход поступает условный файл, в котором перечислены зависимости для какого-то проекта. В системе не должно остаться ничего кроме этого списка пакетов?

Comment: Нет, нужна функция, которая будет проверять установку КриптоПро и нужных пакетов. Должны стоять следующие пакеты: cprocsp-compat-debian, coricos-curl-64, cprocsp-rdr-pcsc-64, cprocsp-rdr-rutocken-64, ifd-rutokens, lsb-cprocsp-base, lsb-cprocsp-ca-cert, lsb-cprocsp-capilite-64, lsb-cprocsp-kc2-64, lsb-cprocsp-rdr-64. Если какого-то пакета не хватает, нужно его доустановить, если есть лишний, то удалить.

Comment: Либо, хотя-бы ткните пальцем, как добавлять в список построчный результат вывода команды. Использовал вывод следующей команды: os.system("dpkg -l | egrep \'cprosp|rutoken\' | awk \'{ print $2 }\'"/

Comment: А какая ОС? Эти пакеты берутся из репозитория или из файловой системы?

Comment: AstraLinux, пусть пакеты берутся из репозитория.